# Javascript - Same name for static and instance methods bad practice?

Tags: javascript, class

In Javascript, is it considered bad practice to give a static method and an instance method the same name?

Suppose I have a class that represents a database table (`Model`) and I wanted to provide 2 options for fetching some value: (1) with an id, (2) through an instance:

```
class Foo extends Model {

  static getById(id) {
    return Foo.query().findById(id);
  }

  static getBars(id, limit, offset) {
    return Foo.getById(id).then(foo => foo.getBars(limit, offset));
  }

  getBars(limit, offset) {
    return this.$relatedQuery('bars').range(limit, offset);
  }

}
```

This example uses Objection JS.

So if you already have an instance of `Foo` called `foo`, you can just call `foo.getBars(10, 0)`, rather than `Foo.getBars(fooId, 10, 0)`.

Comment: You mean like `$.each()` and `$(selector).each()` in jQuery?

Comment: Why can your object be used both as an instance and as a static class? *That's* what I'd start thinking about…

Comment: I fail to see the benefit to doing this.

Comment: What I'm doing is primarily for convenience. I'll update my question with a better example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's fine when it simplifies things for you (or considerable shortens your code or something), but of course it makes it confusing to assess which of the two ways to use. Also, what if I wanted to get a baz *and* a qux from an id? If I used the static method, it would need to go to the database twice. Therefore I'd rather recommend to use

```
class Foo extends Model {
  … // constructor
  static fromId(id) {
    return new this({bar: execute(`select bar from foo where id = ${id}`)});
  }
  getBaz() {
    return getBazFromBar(this.bar);
  }
}
```

so that you can do `Foo.fromId(…).getBaz()` instead of `Foo.getBaz(id)`.

Comment: Yes, that does make sense. If I'm already going to fetch a `foo` from the db anyway, then there's no need to provide convenience functions if they will increase the risk of excess queries. Also, thank you for providing an answer with the reasoning behind why what I'm doing is a bad idea, rather than simply stating it is one like some of the commenters above.

Comment: I think it's fine to provide *additional* convenience functions, especially when they are of high convenience (like saving you from writing promise callbacks). It's just that your original example didn't have the `fromId`/`getById` that enables one to not use the static methods when necessary. That said, you can reduce confusion by naming the static method with its full name `Foo.getBazFromId` or something.